# Azure Resource Manager API - List Resources not including properties

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am using the [REST API Resources - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list) endpoint to pull information about client azure resources. The GET request is working successfully, but the GenericResourceExpanded.properties object is missing from the response. I am only seeing id, name, type, location, and tags. Is there something I need to enable or configure in order to get the resource properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm, that the result of the Resource List endpoint doesn't include the `GenericResourceExpanded.properties`. I think the documentation is not quite right here. However, you could iterate over the result and invoke the [Resources - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/get?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) endpoint to retrieve the `GenericResourceExpanded.properties` object.

Comment: Thanks, Martin! I made a similar post here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/404777/rest-api-properties-missing-from-resources-list-re.html. I'm at a loss for how to get an official response or the most appropriate forum. I would really like to avoid having to make thousands of Get Resource by Name/ID calls.